# "unreachable statement error" while creating a custom WordAdapter extending ArrayAdapter<CustomClass>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Creating a custom `wordAdapter` extending `ArrayAdapter<CustomClass>` shows error as shown in the picture the red lines in the code has some error:

[image]

Comment: it's because of your return statement in first line.
you function execution will stop there as you are returning `View` from that function. and rest of the code will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the word 'return' from the first line of getView Method